# Match formula Excel case sensitive

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an `if(iserror(match` formula in Excel. Just when I thought I was finished with my sheet I found out that the formula isn't case sensitive. How can I make my formula case sensitive?

Here is my exact formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Dictionary!$A$1:$A$2800,0)), 0,  1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE, EXACT(A2,Dictionary!$A$1:$A$2800),0)), 0, 1)
```

It's a trick that's explained here:

http://instantefficiency.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/case-sensitive-match-function-in-excel/

**EDIT**

NB: This is an array formula, so you have to press Control+Shift+Enter after entering it in Excel.

Comment: I have visited that page earlier this week and I tried everything that the guy explains but non of them works..

Comment: You have to press Control+Shift+Enter when entering array formulas. I find it confusing.

Comment: When is press either Control+Shift+Enter or just Enter i get the this error: http://www.lensert.com/bqb.png

Comment: Found the problem.. Somehow my excel doesn't accept the , in the forumla. When I change the , for a ; it works. Thansk a lot!

Comment: @Giles it's worth editing your answer to specify that you need to use Control+Shift+Enter. Not everybody will read the comments! :)

Comment: @AndiMohr Thanks - I've updated it.

Comment: @Giles Nice one :)